# Clipping .las (lidar) files with shapefile polygons

Tags: geospatial, shapefile, clip, lidar

I have lidar files that contain millions of points each. I am trying to filter these lidar files with shapefiles that contain polygons, basically doing an intersect or contain between each of the points with the polygons.

I am new to lidar so every suggestion for open source libraries for those spatial clipping actions will be good enough.

Comment: I guess the most common library out there is Point Cloud library[PCL](http://pointclouds.org/). I am not sure if this works with Geospatial data like DEMs, it depends on your application!

Comment: i will read about PCL , thank you for replying!

Comment: [Here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86075/how-to-clip-las-data-using-shapefile-polygons-and-open-source-software/86160#86160) I provided one detailed example explaining exactly how to do that. Hope you can understand it.

Answer (score 2):

[PDAL](http://www.pdal.io/) contains a filter than can crop points based on a geometric extent. The cropping polygon is expected to be in [WKT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text). http://www.pdal.io/apps.html#translate-command contains an example that uses a inline WKT polygon to crop a file. A simple example looks like this:

```
pdal translate --polygon="((0 0, 10 0, 10 10, 0 10, 0 0))" infile.las outfile.las
```

You can also use a file on your filesystem in WKT in place of the string:

```
pdal translate --polygon=mywktfile.wkt infile.las outfile.las
```

PDAL is free and open source, and can be installed on various systems; unfortunately the install documentation is a bit, uh, [sparse](http://www.pdal.io/download.html). I've listed my personal opinion of the easiest way to get PDAL up and running on various systems:

- Windows: [OSGeo4W](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) includes a recent version (1.0.0b1-1) of PDAL in its 64bit installer (I haven't personally tried this one, so can't speak to its effectivity)
- OSX: use [homebrew](http://brew.sh/), `brew install pdal`
- Other systems you'll have to [build from source](http://www.pdal.io/compilation/index.html) (caveat emptor, those install directions might be out-of-date)

Comment: The manual page has been moved to https://pdal.io/apps/translate.html and, if one needs to generate the WKT string from a Geopackage or SHAPE file, the OGR CSV driver does that with `-lco GEOMETRY=AS_WKT` (see https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/csv.html#vector-csv).